# Terminal colors in Mavericks

Tags: macos, terminal

I am trying to get terminal colors working in 10.9. I have tried ls -G, I have tried exporting CLICOLOR=1, I have set a bunch of different TERM settings and none of it works.  Anyone know what the magic incantation is?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The default `ls` program on Mavericks is BSD `ls`, and `ls -G` is the magic incantation. The `ls` program included in GNU Core Utilities lists with color when using the `--color=auto` flag, `ls --color=auto`. If you've possibly installed Core Utilities and neither of these work, try firing up a default Terminal.app profile (Basic, for example) and see if that works.